# How to know fast if another computer is accesible in AS3 (Adobe Air)

Tags: file, actionscript-3, air, lan

I'm using FileStream to read files in two computers that are connected in a Local Area Network (LAN).
I have no problem to read the files when the others computers are connected. I'm checking if the directory exists before writing the file
I'm checking if the directory AND the file exists before reading the file.

```
file_pc1 = new File("//OTHER-PC/Folder/file.csv");
directory = new File("//OTHER-PC/Folder");

if (directory_pc1.exists)
{
    stream.open(file_pc1, FileMode.WRITE);
    stream.writeUTFBytes(csv.data);
    stream.close();
}
if (directory_pc1.exists && file_pc1.exists)
{
    stream.open(file_pc1, FileMode.READ);
    stream.writeUTFBytes(csv.data);
    stream.close();
}
```

All this works great but if the other computer is not connected, the statements directory_pc1.exists and file_pc1.exists takes a very long time and the app freezes, sometime even sending the "Application is not responding" message from Windows, but it finally responds after a long time.

Is there a fastest way to check if i'm connected to another PC?

Comment: Not that I know of.  What you can do is put the exists check in a worker swf so it doesn't lock your application.  OR use a Loader instead (which is asynchronous)

Comment: @Batman i can use the openAsync method which is asynchronous too, the problem is not in the loading of data, but in the exists property which has the time delay

Comment: Yes, what I'm suggesting is try opening async and listening for an IO error instead of using the exists method.   I don't know if it will be faster or not, but at least it won't lock the UI.

Comment: @Batman That's a good idea! I will try it. Do you know when it is better to use FileStream and when to use URLLoader/Loader? Like which are the best practices? As far as i understand they do the same thing in Adobe Air.

Comment: Use `FileStream` in AIR, it's more robust, especially on Android/iOS.  It's also nice to have the option of synchronous file operations where appropriate (local files),  In your case (network files) you should definitely use async operations.     I don't know if there is any performance difference though between FileStream and Loader, would be interesting to test to see.  My guess is if there was any, it would be in FileStream's favor.

Comment: @Batman Thanks for your time. I'm gonna convert everything i do with FileStrem in other PCs to asynchronous methods. It is a pity that i can't just check if the PC is connected synchronously without a big lag when it isn't. Btw, would it work to use a try catch with a syncrhonous FileStream?

Comment: it should work, though it will still lock the UI.    The lag is more of a windows thing.  (you'll probably see the same lag using windows explorer to visit the same network share)

Comment: @Batman Thanks again, you really helped me. Will convert everything to asynchronous. I would like to mark your answers as correct but i don't see the option

Comment: I usually don't answer unless I'm quite confident my advice will work, I haven't tried it so I comment.   I made an answer though, but please try it before marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know of a method to make `File.exists()` perform faster (likely there is no way as it's more of an OS issue), you can at least mitigate the issue by using asynchronous operations instead - thus avoiding locking the UI.

You can skip the exists operation, and just attempt to open the file async, if it errors, then you know the file doesn't exist and it will likely take about the same amount of time as using `File.exists`.

So something like this:

```
stream.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, fileIOError);
stream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);

stream.openAsync(file_pc1, FileMode.UPDATE);

function loadComplete(e:Event):void {
    stream.writeUTFBytes(csv.data);
    stream.close();
}

function fileIOError(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
    //file doesn't exist, do something
}
```

That all said, since your just writing a file, it doesn't actually make sense to even check if it exists or not (unless you need to use the current data in that file as part of your write operation) - if you used `FileMode.WRITE`, it doesn't matter if the file exists or not it will attempt to save the file.  You'll need to wrap it in a try catch though in case the network location is unavailable.

Comment: i think your answer is the correct one but i think the code i wrong.
The openAsync with FileMode.WRITE isn't firing any COMPLETE event to me, and i think the writeUTFBytes should be written right after the openAsync() method, but i'm still not 100% sure.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#writeBytes()

Comment: I found it:
complete:Event — The file data has been read to the input buffer. (The file must be opened with the fileMode parameter set to FileMode.READ or FileMode.UPDATE.)
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#openAsync()

Comment: right.  because there is no point in reading the file if strictly doing a write operation.

Comment: I think the correct code for writting would be:
    stream.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, fileIOError);
    stream.openAsync(file_pc1, FileMode.WRITE);
    stream.writeUTFBytes(csv.data);
    stream.close();
    function fileIOError(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
        //file doesn't exist, do something
    }

Comment: Yes, that would be the best way if you don't actually need to read the contents of the file before saving.

Comment: And listening to stream.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, fileStreamClosed); would call the close method if the writting was succesfull and it would never be called if there was an IOError

Comment: I haven't tested any of this, (and haven't done a real project that involves file saving in AIR in about a year), but it sounds right.